# How to Install Ubuntu 12.04 With Win7 Dual-Boot

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I had been using Ubuntu for a little while now and I must say very nice a few hardware compatibility issues but that's not why I am here. I have recently uninstalled Ubuntu because I did not feel safe having both OS able to access data from The Same Drive I would like to install Ubuntu on one partition so that its data is kept with that OS on its own partition separate from windows. How can I do this from windows 7 ? I am using a Live CD for installation of Ubuntu. If I am unclear please do say so :)

EDIT: HDD status at the moment is `Windows C:\` And `System E:\` Both partitions I believe used for my Win 7. HDD is 500gb in total.

Answer (score 3):

Not trying to be rude but it is very generic question and if you Google this you will probably find many links with step by step instructions. Try [this for example](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=dual%20boot%20windows%20with%20ubuntu).

Comment: Wow hour's of searching google and you pointed me to the right place! cheers man. this is why i went askubuntu :)

Comment: You are welcome. Glad that helped